# Is that possible to refresh a page from another page in php

Tags: php, page-refresh

I have 2 PHP pages called view.php and Operation.php

1. In view.php I have one execute button which calls the operation.php page at the backend execution - Not redirecting.
2. In Operation.php I am doing some DB activity.

   ```
     * For that I am changing the status as In-progress initially 
     * And changing to Pass/Fail at the end of the page based on the execution.
   ```
3. My question is: Is it possible to **refresh the view.php from the Operation.php page** once it updates the status as In-progress?

Note: without Ajax and Header method(I don't want to redirect, because
I am not redirected to Operation.php, User is able to see only the
view.php)

EDIT : Below is my code
**view.php**

```
echo "<td><a id='execute' href='' onclick='execute_adhoc_prep_page($workflow_id,".$row['Task_Number'].",\"".$row['Script_Name']."\")'> 

function execute_adhoc_prep_page(id,tnum,scriptName){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'view.php', // redirecting to same pages.
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                id: id,
                tnum:tnum,
                scriptName:scriptName
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }


 if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['tnum']) && isset($_POST['scriptName']) ){
               $workflow_id = $_POST['id'];
               $taskNum = $_POST['tnum'];
               $script = $_POST['scriptName'];
               $logfile = fopen("C:\Admin\www\Trigger_next.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
               fwrite($logfile,$workflow_id);
               fwrite($logfile,$taskNum);
              // using PowerShell via task scheduler I am calling the operation.php script  
              }
```

**In Operation.php**

```
   $myfile = fopen("C:\Admin\www\Trigger_next.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
     if(0 == filesize("C:\Admin\www\xpress\Trigger_next.txt")){
       echo "file has NO data";
     }else{
       echo "file has data";
        while (($line = fgets($myfile)) !== false) {
            $array[] = $line;
        }
        fclose($myfile);
    }
     $workflow_id = $array[0];
     $taskNum =  $array[1];
    
    // here I am changing the status as I in DB
    // And I want to refresh the view.php page
    // Once All the activity is completed it will change the status to Pass/Fail
```

Actually, In my project there is 2 way of calling this Operation.php -> one is Manual execute another one is Automatic (TS) That's why I am doing multiple calls. I know its hard to understand, but please help me to get the way to refresh view.php from operation.php

There is no issue in the code it's updating in the backend, all PS1,TS are working fine, the only thing is I need to refresh the view.php after it is set to in-progress in Operation.php to show it to the user.

Comment: What do you mean by "using POST method"? Are you submitting a form?

Comment: `I am not redirected to Operation.php`...but doing a POST to that URL from a form _will_ effectively direct the browser to that page, and away from view.php. Maybe a better architecture would be to post to view.php, and then have some code in view.php which handles the basic post, then `include`s or `requires` operation.php and calls the necessary function from that script which then returns a value to the main controlling view.php script. Then you can echo any further output you want to see, and the browser will still be on view.php. Does that make sense or help in any way?

Comment: `calls the operation.php page at the backend execution`...or are you actually talking about using AJAX? If it's not a standard POST via a form submission please clarify exactly how the "call" is taking place. Maybe show the relevant code to us - that generally removes the ambiguity of descriptions.

Comment: Hello @ADyson I have attached my core code here, please review it

Comment: Thanks. Ok so if you want view.php to get regular updates without refreshing it, then basically your options are a) run an AJAX request in view.php at regular intervals in order to pull data from the server (it would call PHP script which would read data from your log file (or wherever) and return it to view.php, which would then display it using Javascript. Or b) use websockets to achieve a similar thing, but without needing constant polling from AJAX. In that scenario operation.php would probably send a message to the websocket server, which would then pass it on to view.php

Comment: Sorry, I am not clearly get you @ADyson Could you please elaborate with samples

Comment: What part are you unclear about specifically? Do you understand how to use setInterval to run an ajax request regularly? Do you understand what websockets are? Both of those things are quite easy to research online.